# Ускорить процесс парсинга

Tags: java, android, json

Как можно изменить код, чтобы скачивание происходило быстрее?

Нужно распарсить 200 страниц на каждой из которых по 100 объектов. Сейчас в зависимости от трафика загрузка занимает `10-25` секунд.

```
public void getData(String number) {
    try {
        mConnection =
                (HttpURLConnection) new URL(buildUrlUsers(number)).openConnection();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = mConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String resultJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject(resultJson);
            JSONArray users = dataJson.getJSONArray("response");

            mRealm.beginTransaction();
            Users mRealmObject = mRealm.createObject(Users.class);

            JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(Integer.valueOf(number));

            mRealmObject.setId(user.getString("id"));
            mRealmObject.setName(user.getString("name"));
            mRealmObject.setLikes(user.getString("likes"));

            Log.d(TAG, "added object # " + number);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception parsing JSON: " + e);

    } finally {
        mConnection.disconnect();
    }
}

public RealmResults<Users> donwloadAllPages() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
        getData(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: а что вы парсите :)?

Comment: распараллелить. бОльшую часть времени занимает загрузка страницы

Comment: Будете распараллеливать, учитывайте ограничение на количество одновременно выполняемых потоков